# VBA Script Runtime error

Tags: excel, vbscript

I have a error while executing my VBA script

Message is:

> Line 3
>   Char 12
>   Error Expected end of statement
>   Code 800A0401
>   Source MS VBScript compilation error

Here is my script what I want to do is to Convert TXT to XLS

```
Sub TXTconvertXLS()
    'Variables
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strDir As String

    'Directories
    strDir = "X:\X\X\X\xxxx\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.txt")

    'Loop
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
            With wb
                .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".txt", ".xls"), 50
                .Close True
            End With
        Set wb = Nothing
    Loop
 End Sub
```

Comment: VBScript is Type-less so `As String` will fail, it's likely you are trying to use VBA code as VBScript [the two are different](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970436.aspx).

Comment: @Ansgar-Wiechers You jumped on that pretty fast! *(Shame not so much when you leave an answer)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to initialize variable types when using `Dim`:

```
Sub TXTconvertXLS()
    'Variables
    Dim wb
    Dim strFile
    Dim strDir

    'Directories
    strDir = "X:\X\X\X\xxxx\"
    strFile = Dir(strDir & "*.txt")

    'Loop
    Do While strFile <> ""
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(strDir & strFile)
            With wb
                .SaveAs Replace(wb.FullName, ".txt", ".xls"), 50
                .Close True
            End With
        Set wb = Nothing
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: *"There is no need to initialize"* them because they don't exist, VBScript is type-less.